# How to show all directories in a treeview ? (C#)

Tags: c#

Hi there this is my code and I have some issue with this .
How I can add nodes to front of the last node ? 
I want to create my own file explorer . I find very example but it used other tools for do that . My problem is just treeview

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        treeView1.Nodes.Add("Explorer");
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();

        if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {

            DirectoryInfo directoriyInfo = new DirectoryInfo(fbd.SelectedPath);

            try
            {

                DirectoryInfo[] directories = directoriyInfo.GetDirectories();

                foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in directories) {

                    TreeNode node = treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(directory.Name);

                    foreach (FileInfo files in directory.GetFiles()) {

                        TreeNode nodes = treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[node.Index].Nodes.Add(files.Name);
                    }
                    SearchInDirectory(directory , node.Index);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }

    }

    private void SearchInDirectory(DirectoryInfo directory , int theNode) {


        DirectoryInfo[] directories = directory.GetDirectories();

        foreach (DirectoryInfo searchDirectory in directories)
        {

            TreeNode node = treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[theNode].Nodes.Add(searchDirectory.Name);

            foreach (FileInfo files in searchDirectory.GetFiles())
            {

                TreeNode nodes = treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[theNode].Nodes[node.Index].Nodes.Add(files.Name);
            }
            SearchInDirectory(searchDirectory , node.Index);
        }
    }
```

In this section of code . suppose we have 100 direction . Should i add 100 Nodes[0].Nodes[0].... to my code ? :)

```
TreeNode nodes = treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[theNode].Nodes[node.Index].Nodes.Add(files.Name);
```

Comment: No. You should do it like this: Show the current level and the next one. The current one to have its nodes and the next one to get plus signs where subdirectories are found. Repeat as neccessary upon each NodeExpanded event

Comment: I can't say I like the code in the link. There ought to be a good one, too..